# Correct standard to do a pull request when the local branch is outdated against the remote repository

Tags: git, github

The scenario is the following:

For a project, such as *Spring Security* available on github, the following is accomplished:

- forked and cloned
- `git remote add upstream URL-Remote-Repository`
- `git fetch upstream`
- In *master* branch `git merge upstream/master`

It for the first time and all work fine.

A new branch is created to fix or add something - `git checkout -b gh-150` was executed (and none `git commit` was executed yet), it takes some days to complete the job, once completed, prior to execute `git commit` (the first execution of that command for that branch), I confirm that in the passed days in the original (remote) repository code changed

What is the correct approach to fetch the new code from the remote repository into the master and avoiding lost any data from the local branch? It with the purpose to send a pull request to the server in peace later. Therefore the goal is, keep the new code of the local branch, get the new code from the master (without lost any data) and send in peace the pull request to the server.

Even if I do the commit in my local branch and return to the master, do the fetch and merge, my local branch is not updated against the master yet. If I return to my local branch and try to merge from the master to my local branch I would lost the updated code (of course, if the same components were edited)

Let say the ideal scenario should be the same as follows:

- I create the new branch and edited my changes
- I confirmed that in that days there are no changes in the remote repository, so is not need it do a fetch and merge - so the new changes exists only by my side
- so I can send the pull request in peace

**Consideration: *(not close this post)***: I know that git and github are available since years ago, but I am assuming that exists a standard (mostly a new or current standard/approach) to handle in peace this scenario without risk to lost any data by mistake - it such as *the best practices according the experiences throughout these years*.

Comment: What does the last paragraph mean? Is it relevant to the rest of the post?

Comment: I wrote first the same question on StackOverflow - due the kind of the question - it is a potential candidate to be closed. Was suggested from there to post here, so I did do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow that I use with gerrit also sounds like it would be helpful to you:

- first, *commit the work in progress* to a branch. Even if it's not finished. Put a title like "WIP" on the commit message along with the description. You will change this later. Take a note of the commit hash.
- checkout master
- "git pull"
- checkout branch
- "git rebase master"

You will then have to merge any conflicts between your work and the remote changes. If you mess this up, you can try again with "git rebase --abort". If things go *really* badly, you can always "git checkout" the hash from the first commit, and you've got your work back.

This also has the advantage that the merge does not generate a separate useless merge commit in your local branch.

As you continue with your work, you can update the work-in-progress change using "git commit --amend". Including changing the title and description to their final form.

Comment: Has sense, and it is very similar than https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1wnYdLEpgI

Answer (score 4):

At all the companies I have worked with, we have used this procedure:

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

This will get you all the remote changes to the master downloaded to your computer.

```
git checkout gh-150
git merge master
```

This will take any changes made after you created your branch and include them in your branch. However, if someone else has made changes to the same files and lines, you will have to do a merge conflict resolve here. This may require you to communicate with the other people making changes.

If you get merge conflicts, you can do

```
git merge --abort
```

to restore your local branch, then fix the conflicts with a text editor. Then try the git merge again. Git will not overwrite any changes unless you tell it to so your code changes are safe. If you are still unsure, you can make a backup copy locally of the whole repo, try the merges until you are happy, then do the same in your real repo.

```
git push
```

This will upload your changes to the remote server, still on your branch. You can then go to the website and create a pull request. Because you already have included the latest changes from master, and you want to merge to master, this pull request can be directly merged after the review is approved.

If more people do changes during the review, you can repeat all the steps above and update the pull request.

Comment: "This may require you to communicate with the other people making changes." <- this is the crucial point so many people miss. Git (or any other DVCS) does not magically mean you don't have to talk to people.

Comment: Yes, in a small group it might even be best to talk to them before you even start with your changes so that each code part is only edited by one person at a time. This might be hard to do with open source projects, though. You can always check in the git master branch history who made the recent changes and maybe even find their email there.

Comment: Melchior: What helps a little bit is adding things in a file either where they belong (best) or at a random place (not so good) and not at the end - this avoids conflicts when two people add to a file.

Comment: A faster way to do the first 2 code blocks is to simply run: `git pull origin master`. No need for change of branches, does automatic merge. Of course, if there is a conflict, you'd still need to resolve it.